# Office 365 gives bad sequence error on laravel

Tags: laravel, smtp, office365

I am trying to user office 365 in my laravel site but for some reason, it does not work and I see the following error in my laravel.log:

```
[2018-12-04 20:50:59] production.ERROR: Expected response code 354 but got 
code "503", with message "503 5.5.1 Bad sequence of commands
"  {"exception":"[object] (Swift_TransportException(code: 503): Expected 
response code 354 but got code \"503\", with message \"503 5.5.1 Bad 
sequence of 
commands \" at 
/home/forge/owlcrest.co.za/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Tra
        nsport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php:457)
         [stacktrace]
```

I am hosting the website with forge.

and all the smtp details are in the .env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.office365.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=email@odestdf.com.za
MAIL_PASSWORD=fakepasword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=STARTTLS
```

I even tried changing the encryption to "tls" but I still see the same error.

Has anyone experienced this before?

EDITED:

Everything was working, but suddenly I see the following error when I see try to send an email:

```
Expected response code 250 but got code "554", with message "554 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SubmissionQuotaE$
" {"exception":"[object] (Swift_TransportException(code: 554): Expected response code 250 but got code \"554\", with message \"554 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Submission.$
\" at /home/forge/owlcrest.co.za/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php:457)
```

Now I am completely confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the value of `MAIL_ENCRYPTION` to `tls` instead of using `STARTTLS`.

Please also make sure the `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS` to your Office365 email address.

Comment: it gives the same error even if I use tls as mentioned in my question

Comment: What about setting the `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS` as mentioned in my answer?

Comment: a few minutes later I ended noticing that I was still using my gmail on the from parameter in mail.php. And somewhere in my emails I fetch the email from that array.
Appreciate the support though

Comment: It was working but suddenly I see errors again. Please see my edited question

Comment: Please post a new question with the new issue as it's not related to the original problem.